# box2D: move body to the point(touchesEnded)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I'm new to BOX2d and I need to move the body and the sprite from the center to the point where there was contact with a low rate, I tried to use a `projectile-> SetTransform (b2Vec2 (location.x / PTM_RATIO, location.y / PTM_RATIO), 0);` but the movement is very fast and no noticeable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know much about this but try ApplyForce or ApplyImpulse property

Comment: Applying ApplyLinearImpulse body moves, but deviates from the point to which should move with repeated touches does not behave properly

Comment: then try mouse joint try this tutorial -> http://www.raywenderlich.com/475/how-to-create-a-simple-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-tutorial-part-12

Comment: Thank you all, but after experimenting with mouseJoint I came to the conclusion that it is better to play with impulse and velocity, got what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a mouse joint.  From the [Box2d manual](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html):

> [A mouse joint] attempts to drive a
>   point on a body towards the current
>   position of the cursor. There is no
>   restriction on rotation.

Searching for mouse joint will give you quite a few samples...

http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=402

http://iphonedev.net/2009/08/05/how-to-grab-a-sprite-with-cocos2d-and-box2d/